# Dropdown menu to link

Tags: javascript, php, html, encoding

Im trying to create a menu that open a page based on the option selected.

my js

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function goToNewPage() {
if(document.getElementById('target').value){
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
}
```

}

my form

```
<form class="smart-green" name="dropdown">
<select name="list" id="target">
<?
include_once ("xxxx");
$sql = mysql_query("xxxx");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{?>
<option value="http://www.xxxx.co.uk/content.php?id=guide&sub=dog&breed=<? echo $row['id'];?>"><? echo $row['breed'];?></option>";
<?
}
?>
</select><br /><br />
<input type="submit" class="button" onClick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)" value="Find Breed">
</form>
```

however the page opens as 
     http://www.xxxx.co.uk/content.php?list=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxx.co.uk%2Fcontent.php%3Fid%3Dguide%26sub%3Ddog%26breed%3D2

instead of 
http://www.xxxx.co.uk/content.php?id=guide&sub=dog&breed=2

from what i can tell its an encoding error but i cannot figure out what to do about it, also the link isnt quite correct

any help appreciated.

Comment: Those trailing quotes and colon appear to be miss placed: `</option>";`

Comment: Not sure about what breeds exist, but you certainly should encode them: `<? echo urlencode($row['id']);?>`

Comment: Apart from that: check the real content of `document.getElementById('target').value` by printing it to the development console in your browser. Just to be sure.

Comment: Tried everything you said, the trailing quotes and colon i completely overlooked, removed them now. However the problem still remains.

Comment: What is this meant to express? `onClick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)"`? What is the parameter `document.dropdown.list` doing in there? The function does not accept any argument, according to your posted code.

Comment: Dont' store the url inside a value tag. Just store the id in the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function goToNewPage() {
  if(document.getElementById('target').value){
     window.location.href = "http://www.xxxx.co.uk/content.php?id=guide&sub=dog&breed="+document.getElementById('target').value;
  }
```

```html
<?
   include_once ("xxxx");
   $sql = mysql_query("xxxx");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
   {?>
       <option value="echo $row['id']; ?>"><? echo $row['breed'];?></option>";
<?
   }
?>
```

This avoids encoding issues. You just build the uri in the `goToNewPage` function. Pass the breed `id` via the select.